# Source for original article by Euler

Tags: reference-request, math-history

I am looking for Euler's article E19, namely

E19 De progressionibus transcendentibus, seu quarum termini generales algebraice dari
nequeunt. Auct. L. Eulero.
The terms of the sequence given by ux = 1·2·3 … x, and related sequences, are expressed with gamma- and betaintegrals.
Commentarii academiae scientiarum Petropolitanae 5, (1730/1), 1738, p. 36-57. According to
the records, it was presented to the St. Petersburg Academy on November 28, 1729. Euler gave
the essential content of this treatise to his friend Goldbach in a letter on January 8, 1730. (P.H.
Fuss, Correspondance mathématique et physique de quelques célèbres géomètres du XVIIIème
siècle, St. Petersburg, 1843, I, p. 11-18)1.
Reviewed in Nova acta erud. 1740, p. 306 - 307.
Reprinted in Comment. acad. sc. Petrop. 5, ed. nova, Bononiae 1744, p. 28-47 [E19a].

Does anyone know how to access this sort of thing?

Comment: I found it in two Google clicks, you should be able too.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, could you please tell me which string you searched? I did quite a bit of clicking before posting this here.

Comment: De progressionibus transcendentibus, seu quarum termini generales algebraice dari nequeunt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Euler Archive is a great tool for anything related to Euler. The first Google result gives [this source](http://eulerarchive.maa.org/pages/E019.html) with a PDF of the original text.